# In Android,how to stop TextChange event while I set the value via code in Activity?

Tags: android, events, android-edittext

I need to catch the TextChange Event of the EditText, when type something.
But I don't want it fired when I change the value of the EditText in Activity code.

What's I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private boolean listenForChanges = true;

...

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if( listenForChanges ) {
        // Process edits here
    }
}

...

listenForChanges = false;
myEditText.setText( "Some text" );
listenForChanges = true;
```

Comment: Thanks 323go, I achieve it by your method.